# Find the volume generated by revolving the shaded region bounded by the given lines and curves about the y-axis.

Tags: integration

The region enclosed by $x=\frac{y^2}{4}$, $x=0$, $y=-4$, and $y=4$. I know my limits are $0$, $4$. And I have the integral set up. But I'm having issues finding the anti-derivative of the functions.

Comment: If you have the integral, please show it.  That will help with finding the antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture. It seems reasonable to do the calculation by slicing. If we take a slice parallel to the $x$-axis at height $y$, the radius of the circle of cross-section is $x$, that is, $\frac{y^2}{4}$. Thus the volume is
$$\int_{-4}^4 \pi\left(\frac{y^2}{4}\right)^2\,dy.$$
The integration is not difficult. Note that $\left(\frac{y^2}{4}\right)^2=\frac{y^4}{16}$.

**Remark:** I would prefer to use symmetry and note that the volume is
$$2\int_{0}^4 \pi\left(\frac{y^2}{4}\right)^2\,dy.$$

Comment: So you used the disk method to solve? That's exactly where I got to, and for some reason when I integrate it, I'm not getting the right answer.

Comment: I get $\frac{128}{5}\pi$. Without seeing what you have done, it is not possible to know what went wrong.

Comment: That's the answer. So for the antiderivative I got (y^5)/(4y). Is this correct? And then I plugged in 4. I didn't plug in 0 because that would just equal 0.

Comment: Sure. We get $\frac{64}{5}\pi$. Then double because we are going from $y=-4$ to $y=4$. Or else integrate from $-4$ to $4$, we get $\pi\left(\frac{4^5}{16}-\frac{(-4)^5}{16}\right)$.

Comment: Just saw your antiderivative, very wrong.  An antiderivative of $y^4$ is $\frac{y^5}{5}$. So for our function it is $\frac{\pi}{16}\cdot\frac{y^5}{5}$.

Comment: Thank you, you really cleared it up!

Comment: You are welcome. Just a slip in finding the antiderivative.